# PHP from CMD - 'C:\php\php_openssl.dl l' - The specified module could not be found

Tags: php

First time trying to run a PHP script from CMD.  When the script is run in the browser, it runs fine.  But I get this error in the CMD.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\php_openssl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sandbox\singleprop\cp\scripts\newprops\list.php on line 6
```

Comment: Oh, good.  Stuff's finally coming without ext/mysql enabled by default.  :P

Comment: Hey, interesting development.  Rooting around on this client's server, I found PHP installed in two different locations.  Soo...this'll be fun?

Comment: PHP cli can use a different config file. Run `php -i` and check for what php.ini is used.

Comment: @tPlummer: You should have known it was going to be *fun* the second you found out it was a windows box.

Comment: @prodigitalson: Man up. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP you're running on the command line is not necessarily the same PHP environment that is run by a webserver on the same machine. E.g. the webserver might be using mod_php.

To do the same thing on the command line you need to do one of the following:

- Set up a PHP environment that matches the configuration of your webserver's PHP environment (you could then optionally change your webserver config to use this through CGI)
- Run your script by calling your webserver through wget